# Prove by Induction (Geometric Progression): $\sum_{i=0}^n q^i=\frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction, geometric-progressions

Prove by induction that for any real number $q≠1$ and any $n\in \mathbb N$ we have $
\sum_{i=0}^n q^i=\frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}
$

Comment: this is abuse. You don't **need** induction here. $$\sum_{i=0}^n q^i=\frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}$$ is the simplest expression ever.

Comment: @JoseAntonio nothing apparently.

Comment: What is your question? Just show the formula for $n=0$ and compute the case $n+1$ from $n$, $\dfrac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}+q^{n+1}=\dfrac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}+\dfrac{q^{n+1}(q-1)}{q-1}$

Comment: I'm going to be honest I don't really know where to start.  I know that you have to prove the base case, which I would assume would be 0.

Comment: @Sabyasachi : I don't think is an abuse, it is important to realise that manipulation of any kind in finite series are ultimately justified through the axiom of induction.

Comment: @JoseAntonio ultimately justified through induction?

$$S = 1+ q + q^2 +q^3 + \cdots + q^n$$

$$qS= q+ q^2 +q^3 + \cdots + q^n + q^{n+1}$$

$$S(1-q) = 1 - q^{n+1}$$

I might be wrong, so this is a humble question, where is the axiom of induction used here?

Comment: @Sabyasachi: For a foundational course, it is important to make sure that you can in fact supply a rigorous proof for any statement which is intuitively obvious, in this case of finite series, induction justify all, and also it is important to see that this is not directly available for the infinite series.

Comment: @JoseAntonio Okay I see. Although to be honest, I never liked the whole emphasis on rigor. It *is* obvious if it is obvious. Although without calculus, the infinite series isn't readily available.

Comment: @Sabyasachi: For example the Fubini's theorem for finite series it's obvious, but its proof is not trivial, at least for me, only by induction I could give it a justification.

Comment: @JoseAntonio I was referring to cases in which the actual proof _is_ obvious. For instance, in this case the geometric series. I understand what you mean by induction is important then, if you suspect a theorem is valid, but can't prove it, induction is almost always the easy way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Base Case:**

For $n=0$, our sum is $\sum_{i=0}^n q^i$ is equal to 1, which is also the value of $\frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}$ at $n=0$. Hence base case justified.

**Induction hypothesis:**

Let

$$\sum_{i=0}^k q^i=\frac{q^{k+1}-1}{q-1}$$ for some $k \ge0$.

**Inductive step:**

$$\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} q^i=\frac{q^{k+1}-1}{q-1} + q^{k+1}$$

Taking it to a common denominator, and some simple algebraic manipulation.

$$\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} q^i=\frac{q^{k+2}-1}{q-1}$$

*Q.E.D*